# cobertura report appear a lot of errors : JavaNCSS got an error while parsing the java file

Tags: java, report, cobertura

```
[cobertura-report] net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.TokenMgrError: Lexical error at line 29, column 59. Encountered: "\r" (13), after : "\"\u5bb8\u832c\u7ca1\u5a75\ufffd\u693f\u6769\ufffd;"
[cobertura-report] at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParserTokenManager.getNextToken(JavaParserTokenManager.java:2078)
```

---

```
[cobertura-report] 2012 04 23 15:55:39,797 WARN 0 ComplexityCalculator:107(main) - JavaNCSS got an error while parsing the java file D:\testworkspace\HT20120420\src\com\cnbab\proj118\regnlogin\action\ActivateUserByEmail.java
[cobertura-report] TokenMgrError in STDIN
[cobertura-report] Lexical error at line 29, column 59. Encountered: "\r" (13), after : "\"\u5bb8\u832c\u7ca1\u5a75\ufffd\u693f\u6769\ufffd;"
```

---

```
[cobertura-report] 2012 04 23 15:55:39,814 WARN 17 ComplexityCalculator:107(main) - JavaNCSS got an error while parsing the java file D:\testworkspace\HT20120420\src\com\cnbab\proj118\regnlogin\action\ActivateUserBySms.java
[cobertura-report] TokenMgrError in STDIN
[cobertura-report] Lexical error at line 32, column 59. Encountered: "\r" (13), after : "\"\u5bb8\u832c\u7ca1\u5a75\ufffd\u693f\u6769\ufffd;"
[cobertura-report] at net.sourceforge.cobertura.reporting.html.HTMLReport.generateTableRowForTotal(HTMLReport.java:704)
```

---

```
[cobertura-report] 2012 04 23 15:55:39,821 WARN 24 ComplexityCalculator:107(main) - JavaNCSS got an error while parsing the java file D:\testworkspace\HT20120420\src\com\cnbab\proj118\regnlogin\action\LoginEntry.java
[cobertura-report] TokenMgrError in STDIN
[cobertura-report] Lexical error at line 24, column 70. Encountered: "\r" (13), after : "\"\u9427\u8bf2\u7d8d\u935a\u5d84\u7b09\u9473\u6212\u8d1f\u7ecc\ufffd);"
[cobertura-report] net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.TokenMgrError: Lexical error at line 86, column 69. Encountered: "\r" (13), after : "\"\u6d93\ue043\u7d8b\u5bb8\u30e5\u6662\u93b4\ufffd))"
[cobertura-report] at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParserTokenManager.getNextToken(JavaParserTokenManager.java:2078)
[cobertura-report] at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.jj_scan_token(JavaParser.java:10181)
[cobertura-report] at net.sourceforge.cobertura.javancss.parser.JavaParser.jj_3R_198(JavaParser.java:8524)
```

---

```
              if(strRet.equals("01"))
        return SUCCESS;
    else{
        if(strRet.equals("02"))
            this.strError = "已被激活";
        if(strRet.equals("03"))
            this.strError = "未被激活";
        if(strRet.equals("04"))
            this.strError = "没有这个用户";
        return ERROR;
```

Appear afore-mentioned reason is the program has a lot of Chinese message (utf-8) code (such as the above code), cobertura instrument compiled not pass, online information in ()The bat files (cobertura-instrument.bat)  add "-Dfile.encoding=utf-8" encoding or Java environment variable add "-Dfile.encoding=utf-8" encoding can be solved, but I'm in ant build.xml,I add a lot of encoding = "utf-8" didn't solve. Please you advice!。

Answer (score 0):

Try this options:

1. add -Dfile.encoding=iso-8859-1 to your ANT_OPTS environment variable
2. `use <presetdef> to setup defaults for all of your <javac> invocations`